# Design disagreement in Java program

Tags: java, api

We are designing a system that will have multiple "processors" that talk to each other in a network to accomplish some task.

Actually, this is supposed to become a library that will be used by several teams in the company.

We are using Avro to define the input and output types that the Processors are going to accept. So far so good. But now, some of my colleagues are lobbying to provide "more flexibility" for simple types by silently performing some conversions such as int -> long (fine) or String -> int (no!!!). The idea is that the Avro schema defines what the Processor works on, but in some simple cases, we should let a Processor that outputs an int as a String talk to a Processor that needs an int...

We are having a debate about this, and I'm opposing it with the following arguments:

1. We should have more type safety, and convenience now might be a source of bugs later ;
2. With that mechanism, the APIs would become "fuzzy" and it wouldn't be always clear what types you can/cannot send to Processors
3. If the first rev doesn't have that mechanism and requires strict type definitions, we can always relax that and start doing some "conversions" later if it's really a good idea. But somehow, these arguments don't seem to make it through.

What are the pros and cons of that "conversion" mechanism?

Comment: There's only [one way](http://xkcd.com/303/) to resolve these kind of disagreements.

Comment: I hoped there would be some rational, engineering-like way to make a table on the board, list the pros and cons, and get to an unavoidable, unique solution - I'm still naive after all those years ...

Comment: @Frank - yes you are naive :-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this debate can be won or lost on technical merits.  It involves too many subjective issues ... at this stage.  (For instance, the idea that the flexibility will be needed is subjective, as is the idea that the type conversion related API mismatches will be a problem.)

The way I would deal with the dispute is to point out that a value conversion framework will involve complicated (costly, time-consuming, potentially risky, hard to maintain in the long term) extensions to the normal Avro way of doing things.  Suggest that you should not front-load the project with this.  Rather put it off until you've got enough real functionality implemented to decide whether the complexity is really going to be needed.

Comment: Agreed. I would suggest this, and then, if there is no budging, suggest that an interface can be provided that can work between the ins-and-outs, thus extracting the conversion process to a potentially generic and reusable go-between that actually understands what truly needs to happen in terms of converting. This would be a more scalable solution, particularly when the next type, `T`, comes spewing out of one of the Avro Processors.

Comment: I like the idea of adding the conversions later (it goes in the sense of a _relaxation_ so it will always be feasible, but if we add it now, people start using it and then we want to remove it because it's problematic, it will be harder). I also like the idea of separating conversion clearly - for scalability, and clarity. The suggestion so far is to "hide" the magic so that it happens transparently, but I don't like that.

Answer (score 1):

I think the users of a Java API would expect Java behaviors.

Comment: One counter-example is the black magic that frameworks like Spring do to turn text into values when wiring components.

Comment: And also extensions built on top of Java like Groovy which provide weak/dynamic type systems.

Comment: One of my counter arguments is that "black magic" is not necessarily desirable. Sometimes, it's nice that things are simple and straight and you don't have to wade through the source to figure out what is really going on - of course, comments are supposed to be there...

Answer (score 1):

I think the [Robustness Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle) may help you out here:

> Be conservative in what you do, be liberal in what you accept from others (often reworded as "Be conservative in what you send, liberal in what you accept").

That said, I don't advocate writing code you don't need to. Why not do it the way you're proposing and if the system needs the extra capability your opponent is proposing, add it later as you suggested? If they can't understand this, I would really question if they are listening to you at all and maybe think of a way to rephrase your argument.

Comment: I accept that argument for widening values for the primitives, but providing an interface that accepts `Number`s and a `String` is misleading. I would point out the ambiguity of how far will the internal processing go to finding the right answer for you (e.g., will it parse hex numbers)? And, more importantly, why on Earth should such an interface be held to the whims of what boils down to input. The provider of that data should know its format, and it should be validated where it comes in so that it can be corrected closest to the problem. A conversion framework could be stood up in parallel.

Comment: To second you, I tried to send "Integer.MAX_VALUE" as a String to Integer.parseInt... not pretty.

Comment: @pickypg "will it parse hex numbers?" -- You've missed the point of the principle.  The point being that in the future it would have the capacity to without a signature change.  I agree with your point, keep your contract tight, and call a spade a spade, but I can't count on one hand how many times I've had to retrofit code to accommodate a document ID, an invoice number, a serial number or similar that was _supposed_ to be an integer for all eternity to something alphanumeric.

Comment: @jonathan.cone I didn't miss the point so much as disagree with it. Rather than having a bunch of do-nothing methods, or at the very least unpredictable ones, I'd much rather have the tight contract. After all, if you need to convert it to fit the contract, then you can write an adapter. If you need to completely change the meaning of the interface, then the meaning of the API has changed anyway, and changes should be acceptable. Anything more is really just over engineered.

Comment: I agree with pickypg. I don't understand why we should define APIs then turn around and "weaken" them or make them "fuzzy" by saying "oh yeah, we said 'int', but you know, if you send a 'string', that's fine too". To me, either you have types, or you give up on types, but I'm worried the proposed in-between is going to be poorly documented, poorly understood, ambiguous, not maintainable,...

Comment: Look, I completely agree with what you're both saying, that's how I would build it too.  The point I'm trying to make is that if you completely disregard the merits of the opposing approach (and there are merits) you'll find you're committing the same mistake they are which is why you asked the question to begin with.  I implore you to read the link.

Comment: Yes, I am listening to the flexibility argument. But I'm wondering if there is not an efficiency counter-argument to it: accommodating anything and trying to repair probably means more instructions. To me, we should avoid those instructions by making sure the types agree at compile time. I have to go back and look at the SLA's and see if we can afford to be flexible.

Answer (score 1):

If the processor api is strongly typed regarding the types they require/provide, you get a lot of error checking for free at compile-time.  This is invaluable.  If people insist on supporting conversions, I can think of a few, (fairly simple-to-implement) ideas which don't lose this benefit:

1. When constructing a network of processors, the caller must explicitly provide "glue" processors which do the appropriate conversions.  For example, if `Processor<I,O>` represents a processor with input type `I` and output type `O`, then the caller would provide a Processor to convert from string to integer.
2. The framework could include a "type converter registry" (something like `Map<Pair<Class<I>,Class<O>>,Transformer<I,O>>`), which contains a bunch of standard conversions and allows the user to also add new conversions.  The developer constructing the network of processors would have the option of using strict typing (#1 above), or have the framework automatically choose a type conversion processor from the registry.

Comment: Yes, the debate sounds funny to me, because we are in a strongly type environment, yet people want to weasel their way around that type system. I would err on the side of keeping the type checking too. And isolating the conversion functionality, if any, as you suggest.